# Saving multiple dictionaries-of-lists from multiple files to a dictionary, then writing to file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

N files of with dictionaries-of-lists, saved as `a.json`, `b.json`...

```
{
"ELEC.GEN.OOG-AK-99.A": [
    ["2013", null],
    ["2012", 2.65844],
    ["2011", 2.7383]
],
"ELEC.GEN.AOR-AK-99.A": [
    ["2015", 217.30239],
    ["2014", 214.46868],
    ["2013", 197.32097]
],
"ELEC.GEN.HYC-AK-99.A": [
    ["2015", 1542.29841],
    ["2014", 1538.738],
    ["2013", 1345.665]
]}
```

I am unclear how to save them all to one large dictionary/json file, like so:

```
{
"a":
    {
    "ELEC.GEN.OOG-AK-99.A": [
        ["2013", null],
        ["2012", 2.65844],
        ["2011", 2.7383]
    ],
    "ELEC.GEN.AOR-AK-99.A": [
        ["2015", 217.30239],
        ["2014", 214.46868],
        ["2013", 197.32097]
    ],
    "ELEC.GEN.HYC-AK-99.A": [
        ["2015", 1542.29841],
        ["2014", 1538.738],
        ["2001", 1345.665]
    ]},
"b": {...},
...
}
```

This is data I requested that will be used in a javascript graph, and it is theoretically possible to preprocess it even more when streaming the requested data from its source, as well as maybe possible to work around the fact there are so many data files I need to request to get my graph working, but both those options seem very difficult.

I don't understand the best way to parse json-that-is-meant-for-javascript in python.

====
I have tried:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# load into memory
data = defaultdict(dict)
filelist = ["a.json", "b.json", ...]
for fn in filelist:
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
        # this brings up TypeError
        data[fn] = json.loads(f)

# write
out = "out.json"
with open(out, 'wb') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

===
For `json.loads()` I get `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. For `json.load()` it works!

Comment: You must have *some* code you have done to try this. What have you done so far? Can you show your code? Explain what difficulties you are having. A [mcve] would really help you out here.

Comment: `new_dict = {'a' : old_dict, ...}`, then maybe `json_data = json.dumps(new_dict)`, then save that to a file?

Comment: @bozdoz, the old_dict (multiple) are written in other files, and the json module doesn't want to read it: "TypeError: is not JSON serializable", or "TypeError: expected string or buffer"

Comment: @idjaw okay, I'll add some code

Comment: @hiyume JavaScript Object Notation AKA JSON is, naturally, already *"meant-for-javascript"*. In python, you typically use the `json` module to turn a JSON string into a python dictionary and then work with this (add/modify/remove data). When you're done, you turn it into a JSON string again and save/send it wherever it needs to go.

Comment: @hiyume `json.loads(f)` --> `json.load(f)`

Comment: @jDo, you're right, argh, should have read the docs

Comment: @hiyume Cool. I get it though - the syntactic difference is tiny. It could've been made clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading from string:

```
>>> with open("a.json", "r") as f:
...     json.loads(f.read())
... 
{u'Player2': 4, u'Player3': 10, u'Player1': 3}
>>>
```

Loading from file object:

```
>>> with open("a.json", "r") as f:
...     json.load(f)
... 
{u'Player2': 4, u'Player3': 10, u'Player1': 3}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `json.loads` instead of `json.load` to load a file, you also need to open it for reading for string instead of bytes, so change this:

```
with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
    data[fn] = json.loads(f)
```

to this:

```
with open(f, 'r') as f: #only r instead of rb
    data[fn] = json.load(f) #load instead of loads
```

And again further down when writing open for `w` instead of `wb`